# Concatenation of two definition

Tags: c

```
#define ID  proj1

#define PROJ ID##_data.h
```

As per my requirements definition of PROJ should have proj1_data.h

When I print PROJ It should give proj1_data.h ,

Please help me to get the desired result. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

You can only print a string. So to print `PROJ`, you would need to turn it into a string.

```
#define STRINGIZE(X) #X
#define STRINGIZE2(X) STRINGIZE(X)
```

`STRINGIZE` applies the stringizing operator on the argument. It turns the argument into a string, essentially by surrounding it with quotation marks, and escaping the contents as necessary to create a valid string. `STRINGIZE2` is used to allow the argument to be expanded by the preprocessor before it is turned into a string. This is useful when you want to stringize the expansion of a macro instead of the macro itself. For example `STRINGIZE2(__LINE__)` will result in a string that represents the current line in the file, e.g. `"1723"`. However, `STRINGIZE(__LINE__)` results in the string `"__LINE__"`.

Your definition of `PROJ` faces a similar issue. It actually results in the token `ID_data..h` rather than `proj1_data.h`. You need a level of expansion indirection to allow `ID` to expand before you concatenate.

```
#define PASTE(X, Y) X ## Y
#define MKFILE(X) PASTE(X, _data.h)
#define PROJ STINGIZE2(MKFILE(ID))
```

Using `STRINGIZE2` allows the `MKFILE` invocation to expand. Allowing `MKFILE` to invoke `PASTE` allows the `ID` token to expand.

Comment: concatenation as strings wouldn't work if the strings are needed for an `#include`, though.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Should be fixed now.